# Fitting ImageView and TextView in a layout

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview

I have horizontal ListView with with following item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is basically thumbnail and some text beneath it. The problem is - when this item is displayed in ListView the text at bottom is only partially visible - bottom part disappears. Looks like ImageView is not scaling to fit TextView.

But if you put TextView above ImageView everything looks fine - ImageView is scaled down and text fits perfectly. So..why?

Let me illustrate:

TextView at bottom

[image: TextView at bottom]

TextView at top (images scaled perfectly)

[image: TextView at top]

And as requested main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Activity Header"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#6056CC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40" >

            <test.name.Coverflow
                android:id="@+id/coverflow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#BF5E76"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        style="@style/TabPanel">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does the red block at the bottom represent? Could it be overlapping the text?

Comment: For now it's just empty LinearLayout with background color. I colored blocks in different colors to be sure they are not overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/a" 
                android:layout_gravity="left">
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please try this. Hope this would help.

Comment: Instead of giving **adroid:layout_width="wrap_content"                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" ** for ImageView try by specifying a height and width for it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. I want it to scale to fit different screen sizes.

Comment: Using relative measurements such as density-independent pixel units (dp), wrap_content, or fill_parent, is a better approach, because it helps ensure that your application will display properly across a variety of device screen sizes.

Comment: Please make sure that you specify the layout params in **dp**, as I have shown in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I specified params in DP. It looks not bad on 480x800, but on higher resolutions images become smaller and smaller, and there is tons of extra space.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5429/discussion-between-amy88-and-sver)

Answer (score 1):

So hey I had this same problem and this is what I did to get it work:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/main_write"
                android:textColor="@color/color_darkgray"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The trick is to set the TextView and the ImageView's layout_height to "0dip". Set the ImageView's layout_weight to "2" and the TextView's layout_weight to "1". Set the ImageView's scaleType to "fitEnd". Set adjustViewBounds to "true" et voila! Even works when you size up and down so you don't lose the TextView and only the image scales down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative layout for this.it may helpfull for you. The below code

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:paddingRight="5dp"
     android:src="@drawable/a" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

By using  relativelayout, you can set textview below the imageview so that imageview and textview can wrap.

Edit:

```
  <RelativeLayout>
       <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearlayout1">
          //here the textview and imageview code
       </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
       android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1"
       >
      //here the redblock code
     </LinearLayout>
```

so now entire redblock will come below the previous layout..may b helpful

Comment: Result is same as using LinearLayout :( I updated question with screenshots.

Comment: can you pls post the full xml file...may be check the edit part in my answer